# How to have SQL Server generate a sequential primary key?

Tags: sql-server

When adding a new Entity Framework object to a database, how could one have SQL Server generate a sequential primary key for that object?

Edit:

Apparently by creating the table using a query which defines the primary key as IDENTITY (1, 1):

```
CREATE TABLE TableName(ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1), [other columns])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By creating the table using a query which defines the primary key as IDENTITY (1, 1):

```
CREATE TABLE TableName(ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1), [other columns])
```